# Make Facebook app visibility default set to "Friends" - permissions?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-apps, facepile

I have a "web site" using Facebook login option.

Currently, I am asking only for "basic permisssions" and "email" from the User.

As a result, the visibilty of the application being approved by a user - is "Only me".

The problem: I would like to use Facepile plug-in, and show to a user the "faces" of their friends using the app. This is supported by Facepile plugin, with the "app id".
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile/

Unfortunately, I figured out that friend's face is visible in the plug-in, only if the app has at least "Friends" visibility for that friend. As long as it's "Only me", friend's face won't appear.

I don't like the idea of the app to ask "Post to my wall" permission: I don't need it, and I am afraid it may make users uncomfortable.

What's the optimal solution within Facebook platform?

Thanks in advance.

Max